# Is it a good pattern to assert that an object contains certain methods, when that object is known to conform to a protocol?

Tags: ios, objective-c, design-patterns

For the purposes of my project's UI, I am creating a general method in a category on UIViewController that sets up the UI for a navigation item. This particular navigation item has a yellow button corresponding to an action (save, ok, choose etc.) and a gray button (cancel, close)

```
- (void)configureAsSaveCancelIPadHeaderWithTarget:(id)theTarget actionForYellowButton:(SEL)selYellow actionForGrayButton:(SEL)selGray
```

I think I can make this method smaller like so:

```
- (void)configureAsSaveCancelIPadHeaderWithTarget:(id<PSaveCancelViewControllerNavigationBar>)theTarget
```

and have the target respond to a protocol.

The protocol would look like this:

```
@protocol PSaveCancelViewControllerNavigationBar <NSObject>
@required
- (void)save:(id)sender;
- (void)closeThisView:(id)sender;
@end
```

The `@required` keyword will only give a warning if those 2 methods are not implemented.

**Question**

Is it considered a good pattern to assert in the `configureAsSaveCancelIPadHeaderWithTarget:` method if the target contains those two methods? Like so:

```
    - (void)configureAsSaveCancelIPadHeaderWithTarget:(id<PSaveCancelViewControllerNavigationBar>)theTarget 
{
    NSAssert([theTarget respondsToSelector:@selector(save:)], @"The provided target must implement the PSaveCancelViewControllerNavigationBar protocol and have the methods defined in that protocol.");
    NSAssert([theTarget respondsToSelector:@selector(closeThisView:)], @"The provided target must implement the PSaveCancelViewControllerNavigationBar protocol and have the methods defined in that protocol.");
```

I will definitely call those two methods later (save, closeThisView) and so I must make sure that the class that calls this method has them implemented.

Comment: I don't think this is a "pattern" question.  It really depends on how defensive you wish to be and how likely it is that those methods are missing.  Normally, when calling a delegate method, you check it exists before calling it anyway.

Comment: @trojanfoe Yep, thanks. In this case, I am assigning the selector to a  UIButton so there's no chance to check that the selector exists before clicking the button. If that selector doesn't exist when the button is pressed, the app will crash.

Comment: In that case I think your approach, using asserts, is correct, regardless of the `@required` attributes of those methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends on how 'safe' you want to make things. Just because your parameter specifies that a protocol is required doesn't actually mean that the passed instance implements that protocol. All the compiler requires is for you to promise that it does when calling (a cast).

Generally, if you're writing all of the code then it is relatively 'safe' to just use the protocol and not check at runtime.

If other people are using the code, and in particular if you are releasing the code as a library or something like that then checking becomes much more prudent as you can't make any assumptions about what other people are going to do. In this case it is much better to fail early.

Comment: And if you do these checks yourself you can fail with much better error messages. `MBMethodNotImplementedException: instance 0x42 <Foo> does not implemented "-bar:" as specified in the protocol <BazProtocol>` is way easier to grasp than `-[Foo bar:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xirgendwas`.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch So you're saying it's a better idea that I trigger an `NSException exceptionWithName:...` instead of asserting?

Comment: Using an assertion can specify the exception message, it's just a different way of throwing the exception. The key is to create a meaningful message.

Answer (score 2):

No, it’s pointless and extra-wordy. You’ve declared in -configureAsSaveCancelIPadHeaderWithTarget: that you are only accepting an object that implements your protocol, so you are going to REALLY TRY HARD to bone yourself, it’s going to work.

You could be infinitely “safe” about checking if every object STILL responds to messages they say they respond to, but all the extra wordiness just makes your code hard to read, hard to change, slower, and gives you more chances to introduce bugs.

Less code is better code.